# Send keystroke on specific Firefox page with autohotkey script?

Tags: firefox, autohotkey

I have a script that sends End key keystroke when i open specific page in Firefox, it scrolls automaticly to the bottom of the page. The problem is that i can't scroll upwards on that page any more. If i press Home or PgUp key or scroll up with the mouse it automaticly scrolls back to the bottom of the page.

This is the script. As example i am using google page:

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, check , 500
return

check:
WinGetActiveTitle, OutputVar 
If Instr(Outputvar, "google")
    Send {End}
return
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Right at the beginning: This shouldn't be done with AHK! The biggest problem is that AHK can't know when your page finished loading. Depending on your internet connection and of course the server's response time, this can and will fluctuate unpredictably. If you scroll to the bottom too early, the page may load a wall of resources and you'll end up somewhere in the middle or even at the top. In contrast, if you wait a huge amount of time before scrolling down, you'll end up twirling your thumbs in many cases.
To automate browsers/webpages, there are far better ways like using userscripts in [GreaseMonkey](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Tutorials).
If you desparately want to use AHK despite all that, check out this code:

```
SetTimer, ScrollDown, -1

Exit

ScrollDown:
    Loop {
        WinWaitActive, Google ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
        ; How long shall we wait? Not waiting will definitely fail, 
        ; since the <title> tag is loaded way before anything else on the page
        Sleep, 2000
        Send {End}
        WinWaitNotActive
    }
return
```

Comment: I tried the script but unfortunately it is not working. I think there should be `#Persistent` in the beginning of the script, otherwise it doesn't run. 
I know this can be done with Greasemonkey script also, but i can't code the script my self. That's why i am trying to do this with autohotkey, it looks more simpler.

Comment: @user1800997 Of course it has to be persistent if there's nothing else in the script. In my opinion, it makes little sense to include these kinds of directives, since the code usually gets integrated into a bigger, already persistent script. Since you already found out that you have to use `#Persistent`, why didn't you test that first? JavaScript is easy to learn and there are tons of tutorials out there, and I bet there are already working userscripts that do what you want.

Comment: I included `#Persistent` when i tested the script.  I guess what i am trying to achieve can not be done with autohotkey script.

Comment: @user1800997 So my script didn't work for you? For me, it did! Please check if the window identifier (title+window class) matches the desired window.

Comment: Title and window class are OK but still doesn't work. I am using the script this way:

`#Persistent
SetTimer, ScrollDown, -1

Exit

ScrollDown:
    Loop {
        WinWaitActive, Showcase ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
        ; How long shall we wait? Not waiting will definitely fail, 
        ; since the <title> tag is loaded way before anything else on the page
        Sleep, 2000
        Send {End}
        WinWaitNotActive
    }
return`


My OS is Windows 7 x32 if this make any difference.

Comment: The default formating for the comments is relly annoying. This is the correct format of the script:[http://pastebin.com/xGVM1VvZ]

Comment: Has the page loaded fully after 2 seconds? Otherwise, you'll have to adjust the sleep. Also, please note that this script will wait until the specified window is active, send the key, **and then wait until it  isn't active anymore**. Only then the script will start looking again.

Comment: Yes, the page is loaded in less than 2 seconds.